# How to change component behavior from third party library

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm building a website using Nuxt3 for Vue3 with composition API. I don't understand how to overwrite a library component property. Here I'm using Radix-vue. When using NavigationMenu component, the NavigationMenuTrigger is triggered with events `pointerenter`, `pointermove` and `pointerleave`. I can't find how to prevent that. using the `@pointerenter.prevent` does not work. If i try to create a new event handler:

```js
<NavigationMenuTrigger
    @pointerenter="overrideHandler"
    @pointermove="overrideHandler"
    @pointerleave="overrideHandler"
  >
mytrigger
 </NavigationMenuTrigger>


<script setup lang="ts">
function overrideHandler() {
  // Do nothing
}
</script>
```

it just add it to the existing one. I also tried to wrap NavigationMenuTrigger into a custom component but that does not work too.

Comment: Events bubble up, starting from the functions inside the NavigationMenuTrigger component itself, then up to your component where you're trying to override.  By the time the event reaches your code, the menu has already been set to open.  Unfortunately there's nothing you can do to override that behavior, it's just the way the developers designed it, which is the trade-off you deal with sometimes when using third party libraries, that you can't have full control.

Comment: You could fork the library and modify the source yourself or or try opening a new issue on their github where maybe they can add a prop to allow alternate behavior.  I think you would just need to prevent [this line here](https://github.com/radix-vue/radix-vue/blob/f9b0bfe0005e575c7dfe9bbcc18fa3c24738fbbd/packages/radix-vue/src/NavigationMenu/NavigationMenuTrigger.vue#L63)